# CSS @media not working on mobile chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I've been trying to edit some css for my website and change the logo dynamically according to width of the broswer.

Below is part of the css i'm using for it

```
@media only screen
and (max-width:460px){
    /*logo*/
    #main_logo{display:none;}
    #main_logo_retina{display:block;}
    .container-fluid{background-color:red;}
    /*logo*/
}
```

The above works fine on Firefox, Chrome on my Desktop.
On mobile it only works on the default android browser. On Chrome it won't.

At first it was not working on the desktop chrome but it was because of the below format
which i figured out

```
@media only screen and (max-width:460px){
    /*logo*/
    #main_logo{display:none;}
    #main_logo_retina{display:block;}
    .container-fluid{background-color:red;}
    /*logo*/
}
```

It works find on a Samsung Galaxy S4 on chrome.
The app is the same version as mine. I am running on LG G3.

Since i'm using `max-width` and not `max-device-width` should the DPI difference affect this???

Thank you

Comment: I honestly see no difference between your first and second code snippet. As for an answer to your problem: I don't know what screen-size/resolution you're testing on, but maybe it's wider than 460px?

Comment: pls create fiddle for this..

Comment: Yup - test your viewport size, Chrome on android definitely support media queries: [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)

Comment: Screen size should not matter. I'm not using `max-device-width` but `max-width`. None the less Is it possible for two browsers to have different sizes on the same device-screen??

Comment: Just downloaded firefox on android and works fine there too. Only chrome is having issues (mobile)

Comment: Edited my question for some info. Take a look please. Thank you

Comment: There are several possibilities: Maybe one of them calculates the width based on virtual pixels, while the other calculates it based on physical pixels (unlikely). Another possibility is that they render the content slightly different so on one of them it may be just a bit higher then your viewport, which MIGHT introduce a scrollbar, which WILL change your viewport-width. I'm not an Android user and I don't know how scrollbars are handled on Android in different Browsers, so forgive if what I wrote makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Damn, I just saw you updated your question and it's an LG G3 where your media query is not working. According to [this useful page](http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels/) the G3's width is 480, so it makes totally sense that your media query for (max-width:460) gets ignored.

**Original post**

So, this won't be a definitive answer, but rather a list of things you could check, I'm only posting this as answer so I can include some nicely formatted code.

*Scrollbars*

Scrollbars (may) affect the size of your viewport and one of your browsers may handle scrollbars differently than the other.

*Visual vs. layout viewport*

The visual viewport is the size your content has to be displayed, so basically the size of your screen minus url bar, status bar, scroll bars.

If however your content doesn't fit into our viewport, it will be larger. The virtual viewport is basically the size of your content extrapolated from the size of your visual viewport. If that is the problem, you may be able to help your browser with the `<viewport>` tag.

You might be able to determine some of those possible reasons for your problem with the following html and JS:

HTML

```
<p>
    clientSize: <span id="viewport1"></span>
</p>
<p>
    innerSize: <span id="viewport2"></span>
</p>
<button id="recalc">Recalculate</button>
```

JS

```
function calcSize(){
    var win = $(window);
    var size = win.width() + "x" + win.height();
    var size2 = window.innerWidth + "x" + window.innerHeight;
    $('#viewport1').text(size);
    $('#viewport2').text(size2);
}

$('#recalc').click(function(){
    calcSize();
});
calcSize();
```

Create a page with that code, visit it with all browsers in question and see if you can spot differences, either between both values in the same browser or between the same value in different browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the time you put in this but what i don't understand is how can it work on android default browser, firefox mobile browser but not on chrome mobile brower.

PS: I have other queries also for mostly all dimensions but i still can't get it right.

`<viewport>` is already added on header

Comment: Sorry, misread your updated post that you're worried about it not working on the G3 while it worked on a S4. So, just to summarize: It works on Chrome/S4, Firefox/G3, Android browser/G3 but doesn't work on Chrome/G3? I hope I got it right this time. Did you have any meaningful results with the code I posted?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I will try it first thing in the morning since i am out of the office right now